# New-AzureWebsite error "Value cannot be null" parameter ServerFarm

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm working with azure powershell to automate deployment. But I have a problem creating web sites.

Running the following command

```
New-AzureWebsite anyRandomName
```

I get the exception:

```
New-AzureWebsite : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: parameters.ServerFarm
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureWebsite anyRandomName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureWebsite], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.NewAzureWebsiteCommand
```

Note that I have successfully created other type of resources (cloud services, storages, ...). And I have also successfully created the web site using cross platform command line interface.

My environment:

- powershell 3.0
- Azure Power Shell 0.8.10
- Windows 8

Do you have any idea about the error?

Comment: hmm can you post the get-help output of `New-AzureWebsite`? Microsofts documentation doesnt include a parameter like this (but the newest documentation i could find was for 0.8.7)

Comment: @Paul No seems that also with 0.8.10 there isn't a "serverFarm" parameter.

Comment: hmm have you tried reverting back the azure module a version or two? looks like a bug to me

Comment: @Paul I cannot find a way to install an older version... I have tried to open an issue on github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/3028

Comment: Try adding `-Location "North Europe"` to the command. I had similar issue recently and got that fixed by providing location of the data-centre.

Comment: @trailmax I have already tried without success.

Comment: In that case ask for Azure Support - they are usually helpful.

Comment: The issue is now fixed with version 0.8.10.1 just update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue on a new vm with the latest version of Windows Azuer Powershell(0.8.10). But it did work on my already existing VM with an older version of Windows Azure Powershell(0.8.9). After also installing the latest version on my existing VM it also gave the samen exception. So it's an issue in the latest version of Windows Azure Powershell which was released october 27th 2014.

**Update**

I confirm it is a bug in version 0.8.10. See issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/3028 and pull request https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/pull/3036 on official github repository. It is now fixed in version 0.8.10.1.